# Initialization array of object without using loop in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a class named `A`.

```
  public class A
  {
     public string name { get; set; }
     public A(string name)
     {
        this.name = name;
     }
  }
```

and an array named `arrayA` that contains n object of `A`.

```
  int n = 10;
  A[] arrayA= new A[n];
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
     arrayA[i]= new A ("item" + i);
  }
```

Is there a way to write this code without using loop?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to write this code without using loop?

There'll be a loop *somewhere* but it doesn't have to be in your code.

LINQ makes this very simple:

```cs
var arrayA = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new A("item" + i)).ToArray();
```

The `Range`, `Select` and `ToArray` methods are the ones that will perform the looping here. But it's not present in *your* code.